# Rails access joined table's value with single call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I had joined two table and was able to access the value. But to access the value I need to call two methods. I am wondering if that I can somehow make the two call into one call?

```
# models/company.rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :ceo
end

# models/ceo.rb
Class Ceo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
end

# controllers/company_controller.rb
@company = Company.join(:ceo)

# views/company/index.html.erb
# ...somewhere in the view
#{@company.ceo.name}
```

How can I call the above `@company.ceo.name` with something like`@company.ceo_name`

Comment: That's not how ActiveRecord works. Just use `@company.ceo.name`. If you really want to, you can define a `ceo_name` accessor on `Company`: `def ceo_name; ceo.name; end`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`delegate`](https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) to help you out.

In your `company` model,

```
delegate :name, to: :ceo, prefix: true
```

Then, your call will be served,

```
@company.ceo_name
#=> "xyz"
```